# Dynamically adjust width of column in Kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added columns dynamically in the kendo ui grid. For first column I have specified width as 35 and for other columns I have specified width as 100. Now what happens is that there are columns with much data, but because of column width (100) I specified the data is getting displayed in new row.

What I want is I want the column to extend automatically to width as per data.

I tried by removing the width which I set as 100. But that didn't help.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

if you set 'scrollable:true' while setting up kendo grid, you can see horizontal scroll bar.. you problem can be solved..

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable:true,
    columns: columns
});
```

this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebenay/55/edit) might help you..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already set scrollable as true. In that case also it is not expanding the column. The jsbin example provided by you is helpfule. But in that example if I  set value for column dataItem['col' + i] = i*500; as like this the column is not expanding to show the entire value. I want to show the entire value in the column how big it is.

Comment: its working for me.. see this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebenay/59/edit)

can u share your code in jsbin?

Comment: Thanks for help                                                    Added following for kendo grid properties       ($('grid')).kendoGrid({
            columns: title,
            dataSource: data,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: 10
            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,           
            scrollable: true ,
            height: Height,
            width:Width,
            selectable: "multiple"            
        }).data("kendoGrid");

Comment: What I actually want is based on the data in the column the column should expand automatically. What is the way to achieve this.

Comment: have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebenay/66/edit).
it expands height of row - u can have some idea

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. But just one thing, based on the content of column the column should expand. Even if the columns are not of equal size that is ok. Is it possible

Comment: The columns should display content based on the data in it and expand accordingly. I have set scrollable as true and there is no width to grid and the div containing the div. I tried by setting width to columns and without setting width to columns as well, but the columns doesn't seems to expand based on the content and the content is getting displayed on next rows. How can I set the column width based on the content inside it.

Comment: I want to expand the grid column based on the content in the column. However, I am not able to get this working. Any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I was in a similar situation and I had to set the column width to "auto" and make the grid non-scrollable

```
.Width("auto")
```

Please [see also](https://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamically-resize-kendo-grid-and-columns-how#ZVZ-vlMhzEaRzJzCeoWANg) for further info on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var options = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").getOptions();
for (i = 0; i < options.columns.length; i++) 
{
        options.columns[i].width = "100px";
        if(i==4) //I can only filter by index in my case
        {
          options.columns[i].width = "100px";
          options.columns[i].title = "100px";
          options.columns[i].filterable = "100px";
        }
}
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setOptions(options);
```